# Xbox one controller support

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Hey so I have played 7 days to die for a while now. When I first got it two years ago, there was no controller support for it. I quit because that was a problem due to a broken mouse and no job yet. Does the game have controller support yet, or should I wait a bit longer to invest in one?

Comment: The game is available on Xbox One now (it has for a while).  I'd be surprised if a controller isn't supported now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did a quick search and I have concluded that there is no full controller support for the game. However, I did find a program called Xpadder that allows you to map controls to your controller for any game. If you do buy a controller, you will need an adapter, whether it be wired or wireless.

[here](http://xpadder.com) is the link to the program.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own preset for 7 days to die controller support for reWASD using a tool. You can download the preset [here](https://www.rewasd.com/community/config/37223a74c89fe137c43d6841d39e94ea).